# Range Input orient props - Property 'orient' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Trying to create a slider input, which has a prop "orient". I can't set it to "vertical" because of the React input typing.

Is it possible to extend the declaration to add the necessary prop? Or force Typescript to allow the prop?

```
<input
    className={className("slider", props)}
    step={props.step}
    min={props.min}
    max={props.max}
    value={props.value}
    type="range"
    orient={props.isVertical ? "vertical" : "horizontal"}
    onChange={props.onChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this.

```
<input
    ref="slider"
    className={className("slider", props)}
    step={props.step}
    min={props.min}
    max={props.max}
    value={props.value}
    type="range"
    orient={props.isVertical ? "vertical" : "horizontal"}
    onChange={props.onChange}
/>
```

And in componentDidMount do below

```
this.refs.slider.getDOMNode().orient = 'vertical';
```